# Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program when run at x64

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.5, dotnetbar

I have built a small project to show a MetroAppForm of Dotnetbar and it run fine when I run with .net-2.0. But when I run it with .net-4.0 or 4.5 it will thrown an "InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program".
How can I fix this problem, I have tried some way but it not work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug of 4.5 and 4.5.1. You could try to install a newer version of .Net.

Comment: *"It looks like a bug of 4.5 and 4.5.1"* I highly doubt that, do you have anything to back that up? I'm guessing its an incompatibility with Dotnetbar and 4.0 or 4.5.

Comment: There were similar problems with 4.5 on x64 systems. Newest version of DotNet Bar is compatible with VS 2015 and fresh versions of .Net. However, it would be nice to know the DotNet Bar version as well)

Comment: I would cite your source, since I can't find anything showing that big of a bug getting through. You may want to say "install a newer version of **Dotnetbar**, not .NET. I'm assuming its an older version if its 2.0 compatible.

Comment: I think, dangquang1020 could try to update the .Net Framework. And if it wouldn't help - add some more info. I don't think Dotnetbar Metro is too old. For .net 2.0 they had only Office-like ribbons

Comment: I have updated the .Net framework but not resolve the problem, I am using Dotnetbar 12.1 and it run fine at x86 but not x64. When I change to use .net-2.0 the issue is disappearance.

Comment: Are you able to share the sources for your prototype

Comment: I guess that due to the incompatible between Dotnetbar and .NetFr-4.0. Because when I remove the MetroStatusBar control from my form, the issue is not occur. I will share the source on Git.

Comment: Here is the source demo on Github: [MetroBill](https://github.com/dangquang1020/MetroBill)

Comment: Ron was right. You should switch to the DotnetBar 12.5. I have replaced Dll in your project and it worked fine